# Telerik: How to set CartesianGridLineAnnotation Background color

Tags: wpf, charts, telerik

So in my application i have chat and i added `CartesianGridLineAnnotation`:

```
RadCartesianChart chart;    
CartesianGridLineAnnotation cartesianGridLineAnnotation;

cartesianGridLineAnnotation = new CartesianGridLineAnnotation
{
    Foreground = Brushes.White,
    Background = Brushes.Green,
    Axis = chart.VerticalAxis,
    Stroke = Brushes.Red,
    StrokeThickness = 1,
};

chart.Annotations.Add(...);
```

So as you can see i try to set `Background` color but the problem is that i cannot see any change in my `CartesianGridLineAnnotation` `Label`.
Other properties when changed look as expected.

**Update**

This is how i am populate my label:

```
cartesianGridLineAnnotation.Label = "bla bla";
```

As you can see i cannot see the `backgroud` color.

[image]

Comment: You don't even set the Label property of the CartesianGridLineAnnotation so what label are you referring to?

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: Should work. Please provide a full repo of your issue including a picture of the results you are seeing.

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: That's not a repo. You should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve